# alternative to VPC peering

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to enable communication between a consul server in AWS account, US-WEST-2 region and a API server in another AWS account, US-WEST-2. I cannot enable VPC peering because of CIDR overlap. Any other other ways to enable communication?

Comment: What type of communication do you need between the VPCs? Could you just communicate via Public IP with Security Groups configured?

Answer (score 1):

You could run a software VPN in both VPCs and have them connect to each other with some fancy configurations due to CIDR overlap. But it's a pain.

If possible, change the CIDRs.